# Tag suggestion: student-ability

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently [54 questions concern about weak students](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%22weak%22+student), [194 questions for strong students](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%22strong%22+student). I propose we should have a tag for the ability of the students. The question [How to deal with a very weak student?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/77540/14341) seems to be an excellent example of this tag.

My propose wiki excerpt:

> This tag is used for questions concerning about the performance of the students in academia, and how to interact with them.

Some categories of the question: How can a weak student get better? How to help a disabled students? How to deal with useless feeling?

What do you think?

Comment: Since you've asked the community for feedback on meta, I suggest waiting for some responses _before_ creating the tag.

Comment: As for the specific tag suggestion: I find the tag to be somewhat ambiguous. Can you explain more by suggesting what you'd propose as the tag wiki excerpt, and what general categories of question would benefit from this tag? (Clearly, many of the questions in the linked searches are not related to students' abilities.) This would make your proposal much clearer

Comment: Initially I put the tag in the question first before thinking about asking the community. But I agree that I shouldn't create the tag first. I have added the wiki excerpt. What do you mean on the general categories? Questions concerning about students' abilities? The links are just a quick research. Click on the example question and you will see a number of suggested question really ask about students' abilities.

Comment: Hmm, the tag wiki excerpt you've suggested seems to have a lot of overlap with [tag:students]. I'm not convinced that we need both [tag:students] and [tag:student-ability], but if we do, it seems like it would have to be much more specific in order to really add value.

Comment: By general categories, I meant: can you think of some "types" or questions that we get often, that are not classified well by existing tags and would be much better classified with this new tag? For example, [when I suggested emotional-responses, I wrote](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/name-for-new-tag-for-questions-on-dealing-with-emotions-discouragement-guilt): _We get a lot of questions here of the form "How to deal with feeling X?", or "Is it common for people in my situation to feel X?", where X is [one of a list of emotions]_ - those are categories of questions.

Comment: Of course it has overlap with the [students] tag, because the [student-ability] should be a subset of it. It is also the same with [international-students] or [transfer-students] tags. In my experience in browsing SE, creating a sub-tag is not a problem. What ambiguity do you find with this current proposal? I'll add the categories in the question.